# Access Run time error 7 has been happening for the last few days

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error

I was tasked with finishing up a project for another coworker who help and need some help with his code. Using MSAccess 2016 and have been getting a runtime error 7 for the past few days.

Code that's causing problems

**[Forms]![register]![amount_paid].Text = DLookup(current_balance(), "rollingbalance", "account_id=" & account_id)**

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command22_Click()
Dim accID As Integer
Dim stID As String
Dim month As String
Dim parent1 As String

    month = Month_Of()

    [Forms]![register]![StudentInfoSub]![account_id].SetFocus
    accID = [Forms]![register]![StudentInfoSub]!account_id.Text
    [Forms]![register]!account_id.SetFocus
    [Forms]![register]!account_id = accID

    [Forms]![register]![StudentInfoSub]!student_id.SetFocus
    stID = [Forms]![register]![StudentInfoSub]!student_id.Text
    [Forms]![register]!student_id.SetFocus
    [Forms]![register]!student_id = stID

    [Forms]![register]![StudentInfoSub]!guardian1.SetFocus
    parent1 = [Forms]![register]![StudentInfoSub]!guardian1.Text
    [Forms]![register]!received_From.SetFocus
    [Forms]![register]!received_From = parent1

    [Forms]![register]!staff_id.SetFocus
    [Forms]![register]!staff_id.Text = DLookup("staff_id", "StaffInfo", "username = '" & UserName() & "'")

    [Forms]![register]!location.SetFocus
    [Forms]![register]!location.Text = DLookup("school_site", "StaffInfo", "username = '" & UserName() & "'")

    [Forms]![register]![Month Of].SetFocus
    [Forms]![register]![Month Of].Text = month

    [Forms]![register]![amount_paid].SetFocus
    [Forms]![register]![amount_paid].Text = DLookup(current_balance(), "rollingbalance", "account_id=" & account_id)
    Forms!register!amount_paid.SetFocus

   End Sub

   Private Sub Form_Load()
   DoCmd.SetOrderBy "Child's Name Asc"
   End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to set the control's focus to update it's value. You can start cleaning up your code by removing these redundant `*.SetFocus` lines. Also can you share what the function `Month_Of()`  does and probably it's code?

Comment: A main form pulling detail data from a subform is unusual. What is relationship of the datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.Text`. In VBA a data control default property is `.Value`. This is the property to set or get a data control value. Since it is default, don't even have to type it. The field name argument in the current_balance DLookup doesn't make sense. Try `DLookup("current_balance",...`. Assuming this code is behind the main form:

```
Private Sub Command22_Click()
  With Me
    !account_id = .[StudentInfoSub]!account_id
    !student_id = .[StudentInfoSub]!student_id
    !received_From = .[StudentInfoSub]!guardian1
    !staff_id = DLookup("staff_id", "StaffInfo", "username = '" & UserName() & "'")
    !location = DLookup("school_site", "StaffInfo", "username = '" & UserName() & "'")
    ![Month Of] = Month_Of()
    ![amount_paid] = DLookup("current_balance", "rollingbalance", "account_id=" & Me!account_id)
    .amount_paid.SetFocus
  End With
End Sub
```

If field name is actually `Child's Name`, then need it enclosed in [ ] because of space and special character:
`DoCmd.SetOrderBy "[Child's Name] Asc"`